# xsl sort div by clicking on a link

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have a table (made with xml in xsl) in which every column is sorted by clicking on the `<th>` of the table, using javascript. Also I have divs with additional information about every row. How can I sort the divs in parallel with the sorting of the table? My idea is using xsl:sort and the `<th>` of the table as some kind of links.

Thanks in advance

Comment: give a try if possible http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

No, xsl:sort is probably not going to do what you think it is...  My recommendation is to use some JavaScript framework that provides a data table, along with sorting by column.  Get that working in an HTML file, then write your XSLT to produce that output.